# Feature Hashing / Avalanche Effect

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction

I’ve been reading a bit about feature hashing for dimensionality reduction. I understand that it’s important to use a hash function that has a uniform output distribution (the chance of an input being mapped to a specific value is that same as every other value in the range), as well an avalanche/cascade effect (a small change in input produces a big change in output). These properties will ensure that collisions between features will be independent of their frequency. However, I’m still unclear on how the avalanche effect (specifically) impacts this. Could anyone explain why/how it matters here? What constitutes a ‘big change’ in output?

References:
http://blog.someben.com/2013/01/hashing-lang/
http://metaoptimize.com/qa/questions/6943/what-is-the-hashing-trick#6945

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that if you have a tight cluster of input data, you still want the hashing function to splatter the outputs all over the map.  The effect is that a collision will be a uniformly random event, as opposed to that tight cluster giving you a spate of collisions -- or a spate of collisions with the mappings of another tight cluster.

"Big change" suggests that your hashing function, h, should show that h(a) - h(b) is stochastically independent of (a-b).

Is that enough?  Follow up if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The avalanche effect ensures that a tiny change in the input (e.g. words: cloud vs clouds) will produce a big change in the output, that is, that close input values will produce distant and unpredictable output values.